# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get' when executing form.is_valid()

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 2.0.1 with Python 3.5.2

I'm getting this Error when doing `form.is_valid()`

`AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'`

view.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CourseSelectionView(View):

    def get(self, request):
    form = CourseSelectionForm(request)
    selected_course = SelectedCourse.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'profile/CourseSelection.html', context={
        'form': form,
        'selected_course': selected_course,
    })  

    def post(self, request):
    form = CourseSelectionForm(request)
    if form.is_valid():
        if not request.user.profile.can_select_this(int(self.request.POST.get('course_id'))):
            form.errors['course_id'] = "شما قادر به اضافه کردن درس دیگری نیستید."
            return render(request, 'profile/CourseSelection.html', context={
                'form': form
            })
        request.user.profile.remaining_units = \
            request.user.profile.remaining_units - int(self.request.POST.get('course_id'))
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('course_selection'))
```

forms.py:
    class CourseSelectionForm(ModelForm):

```
    course_id = forms.IntegerField(
    max_value=10000000
    )

    class Meta:
        model = SelectedCourse
        fields = ('course_id',)

    def clean_course_id(self):
        course_id = self.cleaned_data.get('course_id')
        try:
            int(str(course_id))
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError("Please enter a valid course")
        return course_id
```

traceback:

```
    Internal Server Error: /profile/course_selection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/acsuser/views.py", line 97, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 179, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 174, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 376, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 388, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "/home/heh/Projects/PycharmProjects/acsrv2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 254, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to do

```
form = CourseSelectionForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: I know this is years old, but your post ended an hour long search. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line `return data.get(name)` from your traceback(second last), at which this error occurred. It is trying to get name from request and request has no attribute get.
You need to pass requested data to your modelform.
Try this:

```
form = CourseSelectionForm(request.POST)
```

for more clarification read this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/